# File I/O Practice.

Tags: java, file-io, io

I'm trying to take names from a file called boysNames.txt . That contains 1000 boy names. for Example every line looks like this in the file looks like this:

1. Devan
2. Chris
3. Tom

The goal was just trying to read in the name, but I couldn't find a method in the java.util package that allowed me to grab just the name in the file boysName.txt .

For example I just wanted to grab Devan, then next Chris, and tom.

NOT "1. Devan" and "2. Chris."

The problem is hasNextLine grabs the whole line. I don't want the "1." part.

So I just want Devan, Chris, Tom to be read or stored in a variable of type String. Does anyone know how to do that? I've tried HasNext(), but that didn't work.

Here the code here so you can get a visual:

```
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    public class PracticeWithTxtFiles {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        Scanner inputStream = null;
      try{
          outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("boys.txt")); //opens up the file boys.txt
          inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("boyNames.txt"));//opens up the file boyNames.txt
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("Problem opening/creating files");
          System.exit(0);     
      }

      String names = null;
      int ssnumbers= 0;

      while(inputStream.hasNextLine())//problem is right here need it to just  
           // grab String representation of String, not an int              
         {
          names = inputStream.nextLine();
           ssnumbers++;
           outputStream.println(names + " " + ssnumbers);
      }

      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Read the whole line and then trim out the bit you dont want. Isn't that obvious? Are you hoping the file reader can magically interpret the data in the file for you and decide what is important to you?

Comment: Lol, no i don't. You apparently can't seem to read. I know that it doesn't. hasNextLine() reads the whole line. I was just wondering if there was a method that would just grab the String representation of a String. so it would only grabs Strings. Like hasNextInt would only grab well formed representation of an int.

Comment: I dont think there is a reader in Java which just reads only Alphabets, There are other ways to achieve - by using regex, replace functions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unaware, Check for this String API's Replace method 
[String - Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Just do a replace, its as simple as that.

```
 names  = names.replace(".","").replaceAll("[0-9]+","").trim()
```